# Differences in protected inner class visibility across packages in different versions of Android

Tags: java, android

I came across this issue in our Android codebase today that baffled me & my colleagues for a while. We previously had a class structure like so:

Foo.java

```
package test.a;

public abstract class Foo extends View {
    protected abstract class InnerFoo {
        public InnerFoo() {}
    }
    protected class Cog {
        public Cog() {}
    }
}
```

Bar.java

```
package test.a;

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private abstract class AbstractInnerBar extends InnerFoo {
        protected abstract void someMethod();
    }
    private class InnerBar extends AbstractInnerBar {
        Cog myCog;
        public InnerBar() {
            myCog = new Cog();
        }
        protected void someMethod() {}
    }        
}
```

I understand this class structure isn't necessarily simple, but it worked without problems. However, we recently did some package restructuring and realized Bar belonged somewhere else. So, we moved it to a different package and have almost the same structure, with two different packages.

Foo.java

```
package test.a;

public abstract class Foo extends View {
    protected abstract class InnerFoo {
        public InnerFoo() {}
    }
    protected class Cog {
        public Cog() {}
    }
}
```

Bar.java

```
package test.b; //This is the only change

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private abstract class AbstractInnerBar extends InnerFoo {
        protected abstract void someMethod();
    }
    private class InnerBar extends AbstractInnerBar {
        Cog myCog;
        public InnerBar() {
            myCog = new Cog();
        }
        protected void someMethod() {}
    }        
}
```

The odd thing is that after the change on *some* versions of Android we get errors like: `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class test.a.Foo$Cog[] from class test.b.Bar$InnerBar`. I didn't think this would be a problem because `Cog` is given `protected` visibility, `Bar extends Foo` and `InnerBar` extends `InnerFoo`. Strangely, other versions of Android work just fine (no errors, no visibility issues). We are able to solve the issue by declaring `Cog` as `public`, but that seems like an unnecessary workaround.

We saw the problem on a Motorola Moto X (first generation Developer Edition) running Android 4.4.4. We did not have the problem on a Nexus 5 running Lollipop or a Nexus S running Android 4.1.2

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you clean your project before deploying the APK?

Comment: Definitely still get the error after a clean. I've even had a colleague build an APK on his machine, run it on his phone (Nexus 5/Lollipop) with no problems, then adb install the same APK on the Moto X/KK and it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class Foo in package a is default which is package private , you should change its access specifier to public to avoid any errors.
Otherwise there should be no problem with your Cog class even if it is protected. Just make Foo public and you are good to go.

```
 public abstract class Foo{}
```

Comment: Thanks varun, good catch! Unfortunately, that was a translation error when I typed out the question (I replaced our source with the Foo/Bar example). Our code actually does declare the Foo class as `public abstract`. I've updated the source in the original question.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem if you are declaring Foo as public as Cog is protected member of Foo and is inherited by Bar, so it remains protected in Bar too. But as it is showing an error on moto x its a completely unexpected one.